# Using git in a multi-user environment deciding, what should be implemented and what should not

Tags: git, version-control

I started using git and already know two ways to use it

1. as a single developer
2. as multiple developers

The 2nd way is nice, but I need to control, what files should really be taken into the master-branch. I heard of a 3rd way to use git, where you can be some sort of an Admin to decide what's coming into the repository and what should not come into it.

Comment: We're about to try this at work: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL: The way I understand the question, that's mostly disjoint from this question, which is about how to set things up permissions-wise. (That is, that workflow is all well and good, but what the OP wants is to be the only one who can touch the master branch in the canonical repo.)

Comment: There are no two, three ways of using git, but an infinity ;) You may consider using gitolite with a custom branching namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Dictator-Lieutanant workflow. This means that only one person (the dictator) is allowed to push to the main repo (the "blessed repo"). The other developers have their own repository. When they feel that they got something ready, they notify the dictatorm and he pulls in their changes and merges them into the main repository. That is the workflow that Linux Torvalds and his people use to develop the Linux kernel.

See http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be the sole admin, it's easy: you don't give anyone else write access to the central repository. There are then a couple primary ways to get changes from others: pull from clones that they publish publicly, or let them submit patches. A lot of people use GitHub this way: everyone has their own public repository that only they can write to (yours is the official one), and you pull from theirs.

If you want multiple people to be able to push to the central repository, for self-hosting, you'll probably want to look at [Gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite), which will let one or more admins determine what everyone else is allowed to do, down to a per-branch level if you want. For example, you could make yourself the only one who can push to the master branch, and let everyone else push to their personal branches, which you can then decide whether to merge. It's quite flexible. You could also still use something like GitHub with multiple people able to push to the central repo, but you won't have per-branch control or anything; you have to fully trust the people who have access.

Comment: "per-branch and per-directory level" <-- are you sure for the "per directory"? I know gitolite can limit branch namespace access, but directories?

Comment: @fge: I could swear I saw mention of it a year ago when I was looking at the docs; I don't see it from skimming now... I'll look more carefully later. (If I remember correctly it restricted only for pushing; read access is all or nothing.) Maybe it was experimental?

Comment: Well, I use it for branch namespaces, for instance `RW+ joe/ = joe` to  limit access to user idenfitied by `joe` to this set of specific branches... I'll look at the docs later too.

Comment: @fge: Yeah, branches (refexes) definitely have very flexible management. I probably just imagined the directories - I'll edit it out for now.

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of Git is it allows you to fork repositories (make a separate copy) and merge (bring changes from the separate copy and put them in the original) easily and quickly. To achieve what you're looking to do, you simply have your team members fork the main repository and make the changes locally (committing to their own repo or branch, rather than the main one). When they're finished with a piece of code, they submit a pull request to you, and you choose whether to pull in all of the changes, some of them, or none of them.

If you're still working via terminal, you may want to look into using a git hosting service such as http://www.github.com/ that allows to you do most of this in a nice graphical interface (not to mention some awesome ways to visualize what's happening in your repo). They also have features that encourage multi-user environments as well as private repos that are hidden from the public (you choose who can see it).